# TripleDES TransformFinalBlock occasionally giving 'Bad Data. ' error

Tags: c#, android, ios, asp.net-web-api2, tripledes

I have the following code:

```
public static string PerformEncryption(string text, string uniqueKey, bool encrypt = false)
{
   byte[] textBytes = encrypt ? Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text) :  Convert.FromBase64String(text);
   byte[] resultArray;
   var staticKey = Convert.FromBase64String(ConfigReader.SecretKey);
   using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider())
   {
       tDes.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
       tDes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
       tDes.Key = GenerateTripleDesKey(uniqueKey, staticKey);     
       CTransform = encrypt ? tDes.CreateEncryptor() : tDes.CreateDecryptor();
       resultArray = CTransform.TransformFinalBlock(textBytes, 0, textBytes.Length);
       tDes.Clear();
   }
   if (encrypt)
       return Convert.ToBase64String(resultArray, 0, resultArray.Length);

   return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(resultArray); 
}



private static byte[] GenerateTripleDesKey(string uniqueKey, byte[] staticKey)
{
   byte[] keyArray;
   using (SHA512CryptoServiceProvider hash = new SHA512CryptoServiceProvider())
      keyArray = hash.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("{0}{1}", uniqueKey, staticKey)));

   byte[] trimmedBytes = new byte[24];
   Buffer.BlockCopy(keyArray, 0, trimmedBytes, 0, 24);
   return trimmedBytes;
}
```

`PerformEncryption` is used as a helper method to perform encryption/decryption of a string.  A secret key is also supplied for either operation.

It is used in a web API application that is consumed by a mobile app in Android & iOS devices.

Bad Data error is occurring with large portion of the users that are on Android, with a much smaller occurance of this error on iOS. Any tests I have conducted on similar mobile devices do not produce the issue.

Only way I can reproduce error is if I modify the string value in a unit test after its encrypted.

The web API uses Async/Await so I'm not sure if this has something to do with it?

Is there anything I miss with the code above that I have left out or is bad practice?

I don't have access to the raw request being sent to the server so I can't determine if the encrypted value has its content appended with dodgy characters from Android/iOS in the request??

My other thoughts are:
should I switch from using UTF8 `getbytes()` to ASCII equivalent helper class if that is causing issues with iOS and android environments

Should I just switch to using a diff algorithm completely like AES.

Comment: You need some hex dumps of the bad decryptions.

Answer (score 1):

1. 3DES should not be used for new code, instead use AES.
2. Do not use ECB mode, it is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin. Instead use CBC mode with a random IV, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption.
3. PBKDF2 is more secure than a simple hash or even a salted hash. The main difference is iteration in order to take more time to calculate the key,100,000 iterations is common for PBKDF2.
4. UTF-8 is to be preferred over ASCII which is too limited.